# Multiple highcharts on the same page

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to load multiple charts on a page by including HighCharts on top of the page. Now when I'm try to load the page I get the following error,

Here's the stack trace. 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function highcharts.src.jsx:6707.

My input JSON is well formed, I tried copy pasting the same JSON I'm passing to HighCharts on jsfiddle and I get the same error

```
highcharts.js
    http://jsfiddle.net/arjunbadarinath/GDBUL/1
```

Can you please tell me why I'm seeing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts requires jQuery to be loaded prior to Highcharts.

Once you do that it works just fine.  In your fiddle, select jQuery from the drop-down on the top left where it currently says `No-Library (pure JS)` and run the fiddle, voila, it works! ;)

I recommend to make use of a jQuery CDN (such as Google) to load jQuery to take advantage of browser cached jQuery.  Do that like so:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I moved jquery include above Highcharts and it worked, thanks for the help!